# Why the deployed Verticles are running on the same thread of the main Verticle?

Tags: java, vert.x

I have a Java application that uses the Vertx framework and Kafka.

There are the following classes to implement a Kafka consumer and a Web Service:

```
package com.example.starter;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import io.vertx.core.*;
import io.vertx.kafka.client.consumer.KafkaConsumer;

public class ConsumerVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {
    
    public void initKafkaConsumer() {
        Map<String, String> config = new HashMap<>();
        config.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        config.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        config.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        config.put("group.id", "my_group");
        config.put("auto.offset.reset", "latest");
        config.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
    
        KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = KafkaConsumer.create(vertx, config);
    
        consumer.handler(record -> {
          System.out.println("Processing key=" + record.key() + ",value=" + record.value() +
            ",partition=" + record.partition() + ",offset=" + record.offset());
          try {TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);}
          catch(Exception e){}
        });
        consumer.subscribe("quickstart");
      }

      @Override
      public void start() throws Exception {
          System.out.println("CONSUMER THREAD: Thread name -> " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
          initKafkaConsumer();
      }
}
```

```
package com.example.starter;
import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.ext.web.Router;

public class WebServiceVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

    private void initWebService() {
        Router router = Router.router(vertx);
        router.get("/healthcheck").handler(rc -> rc.response().end("OK"));
        vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router)
            .listen(5555, result -> {
            System.out.println("HTTP server started");
        });
    }
    
    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("WEB SERVICE: Thread name -> " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        initWebService();
    }
}
```

If the main class is defined as the following:

```
package com.example.starter;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.core.DeploymentOptions;
import io.vertx.core.Vertx;

public class MainVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {
  
  @Override
  public void start() throws Exception {

    System.out.println("MAIN THREAD: Thread name -> " + Thread.currentThread().getName());    
    DeploymentOptions options = new DeploymentOptions();
    vertx.deployVerticle(WebServiceVerticle.class, options);
    vertx.deployVerticle(ConsumerVerticle.class, options);
}
```

The output is the following:

```
MAIN THREAD: Thread name -> vert.x-eventloop-thread-1
WEB SERVICE: Thread name -> vert.x-eventloop-thread-2
CONSUMER THREAD: Thread name -> vert.x-eventloop-thread-3
```

And this makes sense to me, because each verticle is assigned to a specific thread.

On the other hand, I do not understand the following situation:

```
public class MainVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {
  
  @Override
  public void start() throws Exception {

    System.out.println("MAIN THREAD: Thread name -> " + Thread.currentThread().getName());    
    DeploymentOptions options = new DeploymentOptions();
    vertx = Vertx.vertx(new VertxOptions().setMaxEventLoopExecuteTime(1)); // The vertx object is explicitly initialized
    vertx.deployVerticle(WebServiceVerticle.class, options);
    vertx.deployVerticle(ConsumerVerticle.class, options);
}
```

In this case, the output is the following:

```
MAIN THREAD: Thread name -> vert.x-eventloop-thread-1
WEB SERVICE: Thread name -> vert.x-eventloop-thread-0
CONSUMER THREAD: Thread name -> vert.x-eventloop-thread-1
```

I would have expected different threads for the different verticles also with this implementation. Can anyone explain this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You should not create another vertx instance when inside a verticle

The difference is that when vertx is created inside the verticle it only has access to the event loops/threads inside the verticle which would be 2 - since the verticle is single threaded - and that's why the deploy of kafka/http is only on event loops 0 and 1 - since those are the only available to it

as a rule of thumb you do not need a main verticle - do everything directly from your main

Some reference code: https://github.com/asad-awadia/echo-server/blob/main/src/main/kotlin/dev/aawadia/Main.kt#L13

https://github.com/asad-awadia/kvdb/blob/main/src/main/kotlin/dev/aawadia/Main.kt

I walk through all of this in my course: https://www.udemy.com/course/backend-development-with-vertx/learn/?referralCode=063C2D57CCB957C5088C

Comment: If I define the main class as the following, it gives me an error on the deploy of the verticle:

SEVERE: Failed in deploying verticle
java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.example.starter.MainClass cannot be cast to class io.vertx.core.Verticle (com.example.starter.MainClass and io.vertx.core.Verticle are in unnamed module of loader java.net.URLClassLoader @ad9e63e)

Comment: public class MainClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
    DeploymentOptions options = new DeploymentOptions();
    vertx.deployVerticle(WebServiceVerticle.class, options);
    vertx.deployVerticle(ConsumerVerticle.class, options);
  }  
}

Comment: are you using the vertx cli launcher? don't use that - create a professional project with maven/gradle  with a real main function and run it as a fat jar - eg https://github.com/asad-awadia/vertx-starter

Comment: once you have done that then it will work - as your code is fine/correct

Comment: Yes, I was using the Vertx cli launcher as you guessed. So, do you suggest not to use the Launcher class with its configuration? What would be the advantage using a verticle also for the main class (if any)?

Answer (score 0):

You must specify that this verticle is of type worker.

```
new DeploymentOptions().setWorker(true)
```